# What hook should be used to programmatically create a post only when master post is updated?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, actions, updates, wp-insert-post

[Pippin](http://pippinspages.com/tutorials/publish-action-hook-for-custom-post-types/) and  [Jean-Baptiste Jung](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/wordpress-how-to-insert-data-programmatically) have very good tutorials on how to programmatically create content when a new post is published using these four actions hooks...

- publish{post_type}
- add_action('new_to_publish_{post_type},
- add_action('draft_to_publish_{post_type},
- add_action('pending_to_publish_{post_type}

... to run this script...

```
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'My New Post',
    'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

What hook should I be using to do this function **only** when a post is updated?
Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `pre_post_update` action hook like so:

```
add_action('pre_post_update','post_updating_callback');
function post_updating_callback($post_id){
    global $post;
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return;
    if ($post->post_status == "publish"){
        //do update stuff here.
    }
}
```

Update:

instead of `wp_insert_post()` use `wp_update_post` like this:

```
//first get the original post
$postarr = get_post($post_id,'ARRAY_A');

//then set the fields you want to update
$postarr['post_title'] = "new title";
$postarr['post_content'] = "new edited content";

$post_id = wp_update_post($postarr);
```

this way you only need to specify the fields that were updated and never worry about stuff like what was the original post type.

Comment: +1 for mentioning these two important if-checks! I like how you often make this one step further in your answers! :)

Comment: ... well usually more then one ;D

Comment: Thanks @Bainternet! 

If the new post code is dropped in as is the new post that is programmatically it inherits the post type of the editing post, even if it is specified in the array. Do you have any suggestions?

For example the code snippet above creates a new _post_ post instead of a _page_.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

These two might be your friends:

```
add_action('edit_post','your_action');

add_action('pre_post_update','your_action');
```

See: [Action Reference: Post, Page, Attachment, and Category Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions) for more inspiration...

PS. It depends on context but consider also using [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) instead [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Comment: wp_update_post calls wp_insert_post

Comment: @Bainternet but this could be an advantage sometimes: `"Unlike wp_insert_post(), it is only necessary to pass the ID of the post to be updated and the elements to be updated."` What do you think?

Comment: They do the same at the end but wp_insert_post has more filters and action hooks which makes it more flexible